# Can we axiomatize Omnific Integers without the Surreal Number system?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Omnific integers are the counterpart in the Surreal numbers of the integers. The surreal numbers are usually defined using set theory, and then the omnific integers are defined as a particular subset (or rather subclass) of them. My question is, does it have to be this way? Is it possible to give a first-order axiomatization of the Omnific integers and their arithmetic, without having to define the surreal numbers themselves? I know they form a proper class, so there is a risk that they may be "too big" to describe. But Tarksi gave a first-order axiomatization for the ordinal numbers, which also form a proper class, so at least we have some hope.

The reason I'm interested is because of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54526/fulfilling-pythagoras-dream-using-nonstandard-models-of-arithmetic-and-or-surrea) I asked a while back, about finding a nonstandard model of (Robinson) arithmetic whose field of fractions forms a real closed field.  The Omnific integers form such a nonstandard model, so I want to find out whether we can axiomatize them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

EDIT: To be clear, I don't want an axiomatization of the Omnific Integers that's based on something else, like the real numbers, the surreal numbers, or set theory.  I want a theory along the lines of Peano Arithmetic.

EDIT 2: As Emil said, it seems that a recursive axiomatization of the Omnific integers is impossible.  So might we define them in some other way, without reference to the surreal numbers (or the real numbers)?

Comment: Can you link to / sketch a definition of the omnific integers? 

Comment: It's unclear what you mean... Do you want a description of the complete first-order theory of the omnific integers? Or something else?

Comment: @Qiaochu: According to p. 45 of Conway's On Numbers and Games (2nd edition, ISBN 1-56881-127-6), a surreal number x is an omnific integer if x = {x-1|x+1}.

Comment: Yes, I want a first-order theory of the omnific integers, or just the positive omnific integers.

Comment: What is that about the field of fractions? So $\sqrt{2}=a/b$ for some two omnific integers? Hmmm. $\omega\sqrt2$ is an omnific integer? $\omega t$ is an omnific integer for all real $t$?

Comment: Yes, $t \omega$ is an omnific integer for all real $t$.  

Comment: Perhaps it would help focus the question to inquire what fragment of the first order theory PA holds of Om. For example, presumably Robinson's Q holds in Om. Does any nontrivial induction principle hold? e.g. induction for quantifier-free assertions?

Comment: Omnific integers are an integer part of their real closure (namely surreal numbers), hence they satisfy open induction. (In fact, the theory of discretely ordered rings + fraction field is real closed + division with remainder implies open induction.) They do not satisfy induction for any reasonable stronger class (such as $E_1$), or algebraic axioms such as normality, since any of these contradict $\sqrt2$ being rational.

Comment: In any case, since the theory of omnific integers is a completion of $Q$, it is not recursively axiomatizable.

Comment: Emil, why not post your observations as an answer? 

Comment: Keshav, just to verify, are you sure you're looking for *first-order* axioms for the omnific integers, or are you just looking for a direct *axiomatic definition* of the omnific integers that does not refer to surreals, etc.?  In case the distinction I'm making is not clear, first-order Peano Arithmetic does not *define* the natural numbers (there exist nonstandard models).

Comment: Timothy, I am not looking for a "definition" in that sense.  Something akin to first-order PA is all I want.  The axiomatization does not need to be categorical; the existence of nonstandard models doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 17):

Here’s a couple of observations from my comment above.

First, the theory of omnific integers is a complete extension of Robinson’s arithmetic, hence it is not recursively axiomatizable. This makes it rather unlikely that we can describe its full axiomatization in any reasonable way.

Surreal numbers **No** form a real-closed field, and omnific integers **Oz** are its subring, hence they make an ordered ring. In fact, it is known that **Oz** is an integer part of **No** (i.e., for any surreal number $r$ there exists a unique omnific integer $n$ such that $n\le r< n+1$), which—by a well-known result of Shepherdson—means that **Oz** is a model of IOpen (the theory of discretely ordered rings + induction for open formulas in the language of ordered rings). Moreover, the fraction field of **Oz** (namely, **No**) is real-closed; this can be expressed by a first-order axiom schema (let’s call it A), with one axiom for each degree. (This set of axioms can be simplified: in the presence of A, IOpen is equivalent to the theory of discretely ordered rings + division with remainder.)

On the other hand, **Oz** does not satisfy induction for larger classes such as $E_1$ (bounded existential formulas), nor does it satisfy algebraic axioms such as normality or gcd. The reason is that such axioms contradict A (or even its corollary that $\sqrt2$ is in the fraction field of **Oz**).

Comment: This is a footnote to Emil's answer.  *There are MANY integer sets in **No**   whose quotient fields are real closed* . This follows from coupling the following facts: (1) **No** is a saturated model, (2) **Oz** is an integer set of **No** whose fraction field is real-closed, and (3) the Chang-Makkai Theorem. Here MANY means "same size as the class of ordinals". Moreover, one can show that any *saturated* real closed field of size $\kappa$ has $2^{\kappa}$ integer sets whose fraction fields are real closed. 

Comment: Emil, what is a complete extension, and why does this preclude the theory of omnific integers from being recursively axiomatizable?

Comment: A complete extension of a theory is an extension that is a consistent complete theory (includes every sentence or its negation, but not both). No recursively axiomatized extension of Robinson’s Q is complete, due to Gödel’s incompleteness theorem.

Comment: Very interesting! Do they have a second-order axiomatization?