# Replacement axiom and the von Neumann hierarchy

Tags: lo.logic, foundations, ordinal-numbers

Within ZFC, the [von Neumann hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) consists of sets $V_\alpha$ indexed by ordinals, subject to the following conditions:

- $V_0=\varnothing$.
- $V_{\alpha+1}=\mathcal P(V_\alpha)$.
- $V_\lambda=\bigcup_{\beta<\lambda}V_\beta$ for limit $\lambda$.

My question is: **what is the formal justification for the last step?**

The [axiom of union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union) would allow us to construct $V_\lambda$ if we already had a set $\{V_\beta:\beta<\lambda \}$. However, the existence of $V_\beta$ for $\beta<\lambda$ does not obviously guarantee the existence of this set: $V_{\omega\cdot 2}$ in ZF famously models itself minus the [axiom of replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement). This of course suggests that with replacement, this set could be constructed as the image of $\lambda$ (which under the von Neumann ordinal construction is the set of all lower ordinals) under the class function $V$.

But then $V$ would have to be a class function somehow defined through transfinite induction. Since predicates can't refer to themselves, and since we can't just assert the existence and uniqueness of a class function as a theorem the way we can with normal functions, the way this works eludes me.

Comment: The most general 'formal justification' takes the form of an appropriate [recursion theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275981/is-there-a-stronger-form-of-recursion), but in this case replacement gives $V_\lambda$ simply by observing that $\lambda$ is a set, $V_\beta$ for all $\beta<\lambda$ is a set, and $\langle V_\beta:\beta<\alpha\rangle$ is a function whose domain is $\lambda$ with the image $V_\beta$ of each element $\beta\in\lambda$ a set, so the range $\{V_\beta\}_{\beta<\lambda}$ of this function is also a set -- the union of this range is $V_\lambda$, as you suggest.

Comment: Typo: $\alpha$ should be $\lambda$ in the above comment.

Comment: @AlecRhea But wouldn't the domain of that function be $V_\lambda$ itself? Unless it's a class function, in which case my comments apply.

Comment: No, the domain is $\lambda$ -- it is the function sending each ordinal $\beta<\lambda$ to the chunk of the cumulative hierarchy up to $\beta$. As long as each of these initial chunks of the hierarchy at each successor step are defined, the function is well-defined. Replacement then gives that its range is a set, and the union of this range is $V_\lambda$.

Comment: @AlecRhea My apologies, I mean the codomain.

Comment: The codomain is $\{V_\beta\}_{\beta<\lambda}$, which is 'all the pieces of $V_\lambda$', but they're still in separate buckets. The formal statement of the replacement axiom is phrased the way it is (in ZFC) precisely to handle this situation; if you have a set $X$ and a binary predicate $\phi(-,-)$ such that for each $x\in X$ there exists a unique set $y$ such that $\phi(x,y)$ is true, then $\{y:\exists x\in X(\phi(x,y))\}$ is a set. Here $X=\lambda$ and $\phi(-,-)$ can be taken as the binary predicate "all sets up to rank $-$ are contained in $-$", satisfied by $\beta$ and $V_\beta$.

Comment: You would have to modify $\phi$ a bit to ensure that $y$ contains exactly the successor cumulative hierarchy steps and nothing else; as I've phrased it, they're required to contain all sets up to that rank but also allowed to contain more stuff, which we don't want.

Comment: @AlecRhea Ah, that's the predicate I was looking for. Although I'm not sure how you'd formalize "$S$ is of rank $\alpha$" either, seems like yet another recursively defined class function.

Comment: Actually, "$\alpha$ is the least ordinal such that there is an order homomorphism $(\alpha,\le)$ to $(S, \in)$" should do the trick. So I guess that's it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really just a long comment, but the phrasing on the Wikipedia page for replacement is verbose and perhaps obscuring how to use it here. Consider this version of replacement:

> For any set $X$ and any binary predicate $\phi(-,-)$ such that for each element $x\in X$ there exists a unique set $y_x$ such that $\phi(x,y_x)$ is true, there exists a set $Y$ whose members are precisely the sets $y_x$ such that there exists some $x\in X$ with $\phi(x,y_x)$ true. We denote the set $Y$ guaranteed by this axiom together with a set $X$ and binary predicate $\phi(-,-)$ by $$\{y_x:x\in X\}.$$

This is equivalent to all other standard phrasings of replacement over the rest of the $ZFC$ axioms, and is easier to use in the situation you outline above. Specifically, take $X=\lambda$ and let $$\phi(-,-)=\text{All sets up to rank $-$ are members of $-$, and nothing else.}$$ which accepts ordinals in the first argument and arbitrary sets in the second. For each $\beta<\lambda$ we have that $\phi(\beta,V_\beta)$ is true, and if $\phi(\beta,Z)$ is true for some other set $Z$ then $Z=V_\beta$ by extensionality, so $V_\beta$ is unique satisfying $\phi(\beta,V_\beta)$ for all $\beta<\lambda$. Consequently $$\{V_\beta:\beta\in\lambda\}$$ is a set by replacement, and the union of this set is $V_\lambda$.

Comment: This is a very enlightening answer, thank you!

Comment: @ViHdzP Glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

The other answer does not actually give you $V$ all at once. But it is in fact easy!
$
\def\empty{\varnothing}
\def\pow{\mathcal{P}}
$

Let $FN(S) = \{ \ f : ∀x{∈}S\ ∃!y ( \ ⟨x,y⟩∈f \ ) \ \}$, namely the class of all functions on $S$.

Let $SUCC = \{ \ succ(k) : k{∈}ORD \ \}$, namely the class of all successor ordinals.

Let $R(f) = \cases{ 
f\cup\{⟨k,\bigcup_{i{∈}k} f(i)⟩\} & if $f{∈}FN(k)$ for some $k{∈}ORD{∖}SUCC$ 
\\ f\cup\{⟨succ(k),\pow(f(k))⟩\} & if $f{∈}FN(succ(k))$ for some $k{∈}ORD$ }$ (and note that we do not need to treat the zero ordinal case separately).

Let $V = \{ \ ⟨k,R(f)⟩ : k{∈}ORD ∧ f{∈}FN(k) ∧ ∀i{∈}k\ ( \ f(i)=R(f{↾}i) \ ) \ \}$, namely the class of all pairs that each corresponds to the 'limit' of a function that satisfies the recursive relation $R$.

Then you can prove that $V$ satisfies the desired properties. In particular, if there is any $k{∈}ORD$ such that $¬∃!x\ ( \ ⟨k,x⟩∈V \ )$, then there is an $∈$-mininum such $k$, and you can easily obtain a contradiction.

The point is that we can define this $V$ *even without replacement*, and only need replacement to prove that it is a class function on $ORD$. Also, the technique is the same regardless of what recursive relation $R$ you want.